How to perform Spearman correlation between an index (time series) and a gridded data?
I need to perform Spearman correlation similar to the one available here (for Pearson correlation), where I can correlate between a gridded data and a climate index (or custom time series).
The timeseries is a txt file and the gridded data is a NetCDF file.
I tried with CDO (but it seems that it does not allow this kind of correlation) and with R (using cor.test()) but since the two data does not have the same size (44 values for the time series and thousands of values for each grid), didn't work...
Then I tried with Python (using scipy), with ChatGPT's help, and apparently it works, but I'm not sure if what it is being generated is right, since my knowledge of Python is basic. So I need a little help to know if the code logic is correct for what I need it to do...
The code I have is the following:
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import spearmanr

# Step 1: Read the time series data
time_series = np.loadtxt("september.txt")

# Step 2: Read the gridded mean sea level pressure data
mslp_data = xr.open_dataset("area.nc")

# Step 3: Calculate Spearman correlation coefficient and p-value
correlation_map = np.zeros_like(mslp_data['msl'][0])
p_value_map = np.zeros_like(mslp_data['msl'][0])
for i in range(mslp_data.sizes['latitude']):
    for j in range(mslp_data.sizes['longitude']):
        grid_point = mslp_data['msl'][:, i, j]
        rho, p_value = spearmanr(time_series, grid_point)
        correlation_map[i, j] = rho
        p_value_map[i, j] = p_value

# Step 4: Apply significance threshold (p < 0.1)
significant_correlation_map = correlation_map.copy()
significant_correlation_map[p_value_map >= 0.1] = np.nan

# Step 5: Plot the significant correlation coefficients on a map
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))
plt.imshow(significant_correlation_map, cmap='coolwarm', origin='lower')
plt.colorbar(label='Spearman Correlation Coefficient')
plt.title('Temporal Correlation with Mean Sea Level Pressure (Significant at 90%)')
plt.xlabel('Longitude')
plt.ylabel('Latitude')
plt.show()


With all due respect, "I asked AI to write some code and I want a human to check it" is not a suitable question for this website. Please consider deleting it.

With all due respect, I did not say that. I said that my knowledge of Python is not advanced (and, if it was, I would not need to post in this website), and used chatGPT to see if it was correct. But, since this website have this exact objective, I posted here, as I've doing for the past 6 years.

Brother what you can do is first make sure that the dimensions of your datasets align correctly for the correlation calculations, after that what you should consider adjusting the significance threshold (p<0.1) Based on your requirements. Overall your code seems good and with these tweaks it should provide an output.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
